# Flutter return full arrays from Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

LATEST EDIT 2nd Sept:

I am not getting much traction with this, even with a bounty, so I will try and ask a simpler and more specific question.

So I have reorganised the database in line with Doug's suggestions below, as I cannot otherwise reference the arrays in any way in firebase.   So now I have a map of arrays, rather than just arrays.  Like so:

```
ObjectsList  >  CarsMap (Map)
                   - sh899873jsa (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Supra"
                     2  "1996"
                     3  "$4990"

                   - hasd823j399 (Array)
                     0  "Toyota"
                     1  "Corolla"
                     2  "2014"
                     3  "$11990"

                   - nelaoiwi283 (Array)
                     0  "Ford"
                     1  "Territory"
                     2  "2018"
                     3  "$35000"
```

But I don't know how to actually use this structure, as I have never seen this before.   I am getting the first error now with the code provided to me by Frank in his answer below, which I have converted to:

```
 final DocumentReference documents = await Firestore.instance.collection('ObjectsList');
  DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await documents.get();
  Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;
  var loadCarItems = [];

  data.forEach((k,v) => {
    values = List<String>.from(v as List<String>),
    print(values),
    if (values[0] == "Toyota") {
      loadCarItems.add(values[0]),
    },
  });

  setState(() {
    CarItemsArray = loadCarItems;
  });
```

But since I have changed to a map>array structure I am getting an error on this line:

```
data.forEach((k,v) => {
  values = List<String>.from(v as List<String>),
```

The error being:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' in type cast
```

So clearly I need to change this syntax now the structure has changed, but I have no idea how, and can't find anything online.

Previous Information:

I am trying to work out a way to return whole arrays from Firebase so that I can then process the data inside.

For example, I have a document in the database that contains arrays, like so:

```
ObjectsList  >  sh899873jsa
                   0  "Toyota"
                   1  "Supra"
                   2  "1996"
                   3  "$4990"

                 hasd823j399
                   0  "Toyota"
                   1  "Corolla"
                   2  "2014"
                   3  "$11990"

                  nelaoiwi283
                   0  "Ford"
                   1  "Territory"
                   2  "2018"
                   3  "$35000"
```

So for each array, I have generated a random key on creation, which is not important.  I basically just need to be able to return all the data as separate objects.  Ideally, I would like to be able to return "All Toyotas", for example.  That's the end game here.

Here is the code I have generated so far based on suggestions by Frank below who got me onto the right path.

From the build wdiget:

```
          Container(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: Firestore.instance.collection('cars').document('ObjectsList').snapshots(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return LoadingAnimationBasic();
                }
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return LoadingAnimationBasic();
                } else {
                  return ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    children: _buildListCards(snapshot),
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
```

The _buildListCards function, simplified so you can see how it works:

```
_buildStoresList(AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
return snapshot.data.data.values
    .map((doc) => doc[0] == "Toyota" ? GestureDetector(
  child: Container(
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    child: Card(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
      ),
      color: Colors.white70,
      elevation: 10,
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            child: ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                maxWidth: 120,
                minWidth: 120,
                maxHeight: 100,
                minHeight: 100,
              ),
              child: Image.network(
                'some toyota picture URL',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    doc[1],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 0, 0),
                  child: Text(
                    doc[2],
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 40, 0, 0),
                child: Text(
                  doc[3],
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () {
    futureTapHandlerHere();
  },
) : SizedBox(), )
    .toList();
}
```

So the only thing that remains now is to be able to edit/delete these entries from the database, and I think this has to rely on the unique identifier generated when they are created.   I can't see how else to possibly perform this functionality without the identifier, but I don't know how to actually use it, or return it from the database.

Comment: `snapshot.data` is going to be a Map object whose properties and values match the fields of the document.  Since you've randomized the field names, you're going to have to iterate the properties of the map, examine them, and pull out the ones you want.  IMO, it looks like using random field names is making your task more difficult than needed.

Comment: I can't think of an alternative to this, Doug.  Users can populate data in this table with an unknown and unlimited amount of data.  Since the Firebase Database has to have a Field Name for each array, what else can I use as the Field Names?

Comment: You could instead use a single field, and nest the maps of random IDs under that.  Then you can access that single field and again iterate the nested map fields so you know exactly which of the nested fields were entered by the user (as opposed to other fields with different meanings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not solved by doing it in the format listed in the question, and I was trying it this way as another user told me I would not be able to delete individual arrays unless they sat under a map.

The answer here is that the above is not true, and the solution was to ditch the map altogether and just have the arrays.  What I did here as it makes sense to me is to have the first object in the array be the unique code, so I can reference it easily, like so:

```
ObjectsList  >  
(document)      - sh899873jsa (Array)
                 0  "sh899873jsa" 
                 1  "Toyota"
                 2  "Supra"
                 3  "1996"
                 4  "$4990"

               - hasd823j399 (Array)
                 0  "hasd823j399"
                 1  "Toyota"
                 2  "Corolla"
                 3  "2014"
                 4  "$11990"

               - nelaoiwi283 (Array)
                 0  "nelaoiwi283"
                 1  "Ford"
                 2  "Territory"
                 3  "2018"
                 4  "$35000"
```

These can then be referenced directly and deleted easily:

```
_deleteMenuItem() async {
  await deleteSelectedImages();
  DocumentReference documentReference = Firestore.instance.collection('data').document('ObjectsList');
  documentReference.updateData({
    CarsMap[selectedItem][0]: FieldValue.delete(),
  });
}
```

Where CarsMap is the loaded array of car objects at run time, and selectedItem is the item selected in the UI from the ListTiles.  So step 1 was to grab all the data from Firebase and populate it into the CarsMap array.    Step 2 was to build ListTiles from this array.  Step 3 was to have an onTap method that selects the current ListTile, and then store the index of that tile into selectedItem.

This does what I need it to do, and users can now populate and remove arrays from my database as required.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `snapshot.data()` returns you a `Map<String, dynamic>`. You can loop over the entries in this map, and then get the first child of each (array) value.

So something like this:

List.from(event.snapshot.value as List)

```
final DocumentReference documents = await Firestore.instance.collection('cars').document('ObjectsList');
DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await documents.get();
Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
var cars = [];
data.forEach((k,v) => {
  var values = List<String>.from(v as List<dynamic>);
  cars.add(values[0]);
})

setState(() {
  arrayOfCars = cars
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Frank.   On the line:     Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();   I am getting the error:   "The expression does not evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked" on snapshot.data()

Comment: Oh, it seems you just need to remove the parentheses, so the line becomes:   Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data;    was a lucky guess!

Comment: Ok also this line:    data.forEach((k,v) => {      needs to be    data.forEach((k,v) => () { and then close the function:   }) becomes });    After all that, it now compiles, but unfortunately does not return any data at all.   When I print arrayOfCars, it is just blank each time.  So not really sure where it is going wrong.

Comment: Ok I am getting somewhere with your code, but am having to change little bits.   Suspect you probably wrote this off the top of your head, which is heaps impressive.   Just trying to muddle through it then will post update.

Comment: Thanks for working through it Bisclavret. If you find problems like that, you can just edit the answer to fix them. The only one that is a big surprise to be is the first one, as I've always used `data()` to access the data from a snapshot, and all documentation suggests that is still the case: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html

Comment: Ok I have made some excellent progress with this.   I will update and post an update to this question, not only to show the code but also as there is a vital key ingredient missing.   I need to be able to edit/delete cars from the list, which relies on the unique keys I am generating, but I do not know how to actually access these, and return them from the database.

Answer (score 0):

There was no answer to this question.  I am still struggling and have lost 11 days of production time on this so far.

Thanks for the suggestions from people trying to help, but this ended up going nowhere and I still have no solved it.